# VB Graphics : copy region (determined by 4 points ) to rectangle

Tags: graphics, vb6

Programming language: VB6

I have a problem to copy region within a picture determined by 4 points (p1,p2,p3,p4), and reskew it to a another picture with fixed rectangle (P1,P2,P3,P4), as shown:

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the details but you need StretchBlit.